# Refresh element using only JS console

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am needing to refresh only one element using the JS console, rather than refreshing the whole page. I've got code that already works, but it depends on refreshing the page.

```
  if (document.readyState === "complete") { vote(); }


function vote() { 
//Do some stuff

setTimeout(function(){ 
location.reload(); 
}, 500);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with refreshing one elem??

Comment: I would like to reload only one specific element, say I had a div id with #element. Instead of refreshing the page, I would like to only refresh that specified element.

Comment: I think you dont understand the sense of HTML

Answer (score 2):

```js
function reload(){
  var container = document.getElementById("testDiv");
  var newContent = "After reload";
  container.innerHTML= newContent;
}
```

```html
<button><a href="javascript: reload()">Reload</a></button>
<br/>
<div id="testDiv">
Before reload.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just want to reload an iframe:

```
your normal html
<iframe src="page that should be reloaded.html">old browser</iframe>
<script>
function reload(){ document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].reload();
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: Is there any way this could be done straight from the console though?

Comment: @Jared Bledsoe : nope. Please clarify what you mean with "refreshing". My code includes separately loaded html, that can be refreshed (server request). If you want to insert your oen content, see other answer. If youre trying to update the shown content, based on the content you applied to an js elem, simply you dont. The browser does this for you

Answer (score 1):

What does refreshing one element mean? If you have a div with an id of element then you can just change the contents of that div using javascript and it will make the changes in your html. If the div contains "HI" then you can use document.getElementById("element").innerHTML and change it to whatever you want. Or you can change its attributes, you can add elements inside that div using javascript as well, what is it you are trying to do exactly? I assume that no matter what it is, you can just grab that element via its id and change it whenever you want it to refresh.

Comment: Im wanting to "refresh" an element that frequently changes values. Say it increases by 5 every second, rather than refreshing I need to just refresh from the JS console.